# How do you handle Reach in Dungeon World?

Tags: combat, dungeon-world, reach

**How does reach actually work?**

If I am wielding a long spear against a goblin with a dagger ("Staying far out of its reach, I make quick thrusts at the goblin's head!"), do I roll Hack and Slash? Do I simply roll damage? What happens if I roll Hack and Slash and roll an 8?

And if I have a spiked shield (hand weapon) and want to attack a large ogre with a halberd (reach weapon), do I have to Defy Danger to get up close, but then get to hit automatically once I'm close? What about if I had a longsword (close), so our weapons are only 1 range-category different. Would that turn it into a Hack and Slash, or would it be a Defy Danger first to get in range, and then a Hack and Slash to attack?

Here are two example situations I'd like to understand better:

1) Player with reach attacks goblin with hand weapon, using his reach to stay safe.

2) Player with a hand weapon attacks an ogre with a reach weapon, inside of the ogre's effective range.

In example 1, if you have to roll Hack and Slash for that, then that means there is no difference between a reach weapon and a non-reach weapon, so you're ignoring the narrative.

In example 2, if you have to roll Hack and Slash for that, then it means the ogre can attack the player in a way that violates the rules (the rules say that a player with a reach weapon can't use it against an enemy with a hand weapon that manages to get up close). So monsters can violate that rule, but players have to follow it? What?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If I am wielding a long spear against a goblin with a dagger ("Staying far out of it's reach, I make quick thrusts at the goblin's head!"), do I roll Hack and Slash? Do I simply roll damage? What happens if I roll Hack and Slash and roll an 8?

You roll hack and slash as long as, narratively, it makes sense for the goblin to be at the spear's weapon range. If the goblin is already on top of you, you can't use hack and slash to damage the goblin with the spear.

The 7-9 result, "the enemy makes an attack against you" could be a monster move or a GM move.

> ### Basic Moves: Hack and Slash
>
> The enemy’s counterattack can be any GM move made directly with that creature. A goblin might just attack you back, or they might jam a poisoned needle into your veins. Life’s tough, isn’t it?
>
> ### Monster Setting 1, ￼Cavern Dwellers: Goblin
>
> - Charge!
> - Call more goblins
> - Retreat and return with (many) more

Charging you with its dagger could also be reasonable, since "Charge" is a goblin move. The fact that you're trying to stay out of its reach is being compromised by its move and your middling roll. Dealing damage probably isn't appropriate, but the goblin could get inside your spear range (sign of an approaching threat, show off a downside to their equipment).

> And if I have a spiked shield (hand weapon) and want to attack a large ogre with a halberd (reach weapon), do I have to Defy Danger to get up close, but then get to hit automatically once I'm close?

It's a defy danger to get close because the danger is an ogre with a reach weapon, without which you can't hack and slash. But, having defied the danger, you still have to make a hack and slash roll if you want to jab the ogre.

Answer (score 5):

In Dungeon World, always remember that moves follow the narrative, rather than the other way around.

First, to look a the rules, on p. 324

> Weapons have tags to indicate the range at which they are useful.
>   Dungeon World doesn’t inflict penalties or grant bonuses for “optimal
>   range” or the like, but if your weapon says Hand and an enemy is ten
>   yards away, a player would have a hard time justifying using that
>   weapon against him.

So, what does this say towards answering your question?  If the player describes his attack and position in terms that utilize the tag, i.e. *"Drogon pins the orc in the tines of his spetum, keeping him at bay."*, if he succeeds at his roll (i.e. 10+), he does just that, keeping the orc at bay.  If you roll an qualified success (i.e. 7–9), then Drogon's execution is a bit off; the GM gets to make a move against Drogon.  If Drogon has a spear, and the orc is behind a grate, then he couldn't really hit him with a dagger — but he could poke the spear through the grate and still take out the Orc.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment... it seems like you are saying there is no difference between "I stab at him from well out of his reach" and "I swing my sword at him, hoping to sidestep and avoid his swing". So what you're saying is the narrative **doesn't** matter.

Comment: @ShepherdsPie "7-9: the enemy makes an attack against you" just means you get to make a GM Move against the player. It doesn't have to be a physical attack. "Put them in a spot" or "call for reinforcements" is equally acceptable as "Do damage as established". Doing damage isn't your only option for a 7-9 Hack and Slash result. Even the GM can't make a move that the fiction disallows, so you have to use that goblin to do a GM move that follows. If bars are in the way you can't deal stabbing damage, so instead have it look behind the PC and shout with joy that the ogre's arrived ("show signs").

Answer (score 1):

We wanted spears to be a real stake (pun intended), so we house-ruled reach rules. Spears have a penalty to Hack 'n Slash against shorter weapons.

> **When an enemy has reach** and is ready for you, you need to Defy Danger to get in their range. A typical 7-9 has you choose between staying out reach or taking damage; 6- means both.

Then the GM has that enemy react to your new position. As for players having reach:

> **When you use your reach** to threaten incoming enemies, roll +Str. 10+ gives you a free attack against one of them and keep them at bay; 7-9 has you choose one.

In any case, depending on GM feel, bypassing reach can directly lead to rolling damage or can instead go to Hack 'n Slash (typically with the spear-user switching weapons).

Another house-rule: among non-reach melee weapons, having a longer or shorter weapon than your enemy respectively grants +1 or -1 to Hack 'n Slash. The benefits of shorter weapons are their availability, concealability and advantage in grappling situations.